# How to search for specific text in span in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the HTML as:

```
<tr>
<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label1_0">Engineering Mechanics</span>
</tr>
<tr>
<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label1_2">Engineering Mechanics</span>
</tr>
...
```

my code for getting span text is :

```
trs = soup.find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    spans = tr.find_all('span')
    if spans.id == "ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label***":
        print spans.string
```

In this line `spans.id == "ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label***"`, I want to get all the ids having the same text at the beginning but different numbers at the last (like the above contents the number at last - `1_0`). But my code is an error. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your current code does not work for multiple reasons:

- the `spans` is actually a `ResultSet` object - a list of tags and it does not have an `id` attribute
- even if `spans` would be a single `Tag` instance, the `spans.id` would not get you the `id` attribute - it would actually mean `spans.find("id")` which would result into `None`. To get the attribute value of a `Tag`, use it like a dictionary, e.g: `span["id"]`
- you cannot do the partial match with `==` and `*` in the string

We can do better and solve it in a cleaner way anyway.

---

The easiest thing to do is to use the "starts with" [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for elm in soup.select("span[id^=ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label]"):
    print(elm.get_text())
```

Or, if via `find_all()`, you can either use a [filtering function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):

```
for elm in soup.find_all("span", id=lambda value: value and value.startswith("ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label"):
    print(elm.get_text())
```

Or, a [regular expression](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression):

```
import re

for elm in soup.find_all("span", id=re.compile("^ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label")):
    print(elm.get_text())
```

where `^` denotes the beginning of a string.

Comment: @slpcf sure, please see the same answer :) I mean, does not it answer the question?

Comment: Thank you. Can I use something like this `  print(elm[2].get_text())`?

Comment: @slpcf well, no, `elm` is a single span element with the matching partial id, why are you asking?

Comment: Sir, I want to print texts like "Engineering mechanics" (see HTML above in question) first, then skip the next output and then print the third text like so one.

Comment: @slpcf sure, the straightforward way to do that could be to use `enumerate` to check the index: `for index, elm in enumerate(soup.find_all("span", id=re.compile("^ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_reminder_Label"))):` and then check the value of `index` inside the loop. Hope that helps.